# Replacement brand for Apple ANSI wired keyboard with numeric keypad?

Tags: usb

I've recently (December 2022) learned that Apple no longer sells wired keyboards. My touch-typing has become extremely optimized for one of their USB keyboards and I'd like to find a suitable replacement. I use older Linux hardware, so anything with a battery or wireless-only features is not suitable, nor am I interested in increasing the number of adapters and dongles in my apartment to fit a new wireless keyboard to older hardware (these can be lost, and introduce points of failure).

I do not know the official name/# of this model, but it can be described as: Aluminum body, USB-A cable, ANSI layout, shallow profile, slight angle, thin keys, numeric keypad, and essentially indestructible until you spill coffee on it.

I would like a replacement that replicates the discontinued keyboard in terms of

- Wrist and posture ergonomics: A similarly shallow profile and slight angle, identical hand position when typing.
- Matching kinematics: Keys of comparable size, position, thickness, force profiles, travel distances, and acoustic and mechanical properties associate with key-press and release.
- Matching features: USB-A ANSI layout with navigation keys and numeric keypad.
- Nothing too lightweight: something that will stay in place on the desk.
- No wireless features or batteries, thank you very much.
- Durable enough to last ten years with a fair amount of mechanical abuse.

Nice to haves:

- Coffee proof
- Easy to source in the UK
- From a manufacturer with a good reputation for buy-it-for life hardware, professionalism in business transactions, *and respecting their users.*
- Backlit? Maybe? If it can be achieved without compromising performance/durability?

***Would anyone happen to know of any keyboards that approximate these specifications?***

I *can* provide arguments defending my sensorimotor inflexibility and arbitrary hardware preferences, but I trust this community is sufficiently familiar with diversity, both neurological and in terms of practical and aesthetic technology preferences (:

Other *possibly* relevant notes:

- The keyboard will be used with older PCs running Linux
- I'll need to buy it in the UK, but really do *need* the ANSI layout: I cannot for the life of me type on the ISO layouts with their weird vertical enter key (it requires shifting hand position on the home row and violates some other textbook best-practices for human-computer interface design). I spent three years trying: Thought-train derailing typos every three minutes, and never recovered typing proficiency. Everything went back to normal when I switched back to ANSI. I guess a neuroplasticity window closed.
- I *have* looked on Ebay for old copies of the desired model, but the ANSI version just isn't common in the UK secondary market.
- US layout preferred but as long as the key geometry matches the form US-layout USB-A ANSI Apple aluminum keyboard with numeric keypad, it will be good.

### Updates:

Before @Tetsujin's answer, I impulse bought an aluminum keyboard from a company called Matias, which *claimed* to be making clones of Apple's old keyboards. The keyboard arrived. It resembles the apple keyboard, but isn't sparking joy.

- Yes, the key spacing and profile matches, but the manufacturing quality is simply good, not excellent. The keys themselves are not uniformly aligned with the cutouts in the aluminum plate.
- The keys feel *"off"*. I'm not sure what it is, it feels like they are slightly higher, or have slightly further travel distance, or are in some other way weightier and more sluggish. I keep glancing the edges of the keys, suggesting they have further travel distance or are less rounded on the edges. Apple keyboards do wear in over time, so part of this might be me comparing an aged Apple keyboard with something new. But we'll see. There was just *something* about the old Apple keyboards that allowed extremely rapid typing (I suspect it was minimizing the weight of the keys, and optimizing the travel distance and force to provide unambiguous tactile feedback while minimizing force and motion)

However, I *can* confirm, per @Tetsujin's answer, that the keyword "Apple A1243 US" *does* return some suppliers on eBay within the UK. I will be ordering one of those now.

In the long term, the secondary market for "Apple A1243 US" *will* dry up, in which case the search remains open for a keyboard that is:

- Robust, Low profile, high-quality ANSI 109-key layout or similar with
- Spacing, height, force, travel distance comparable to Apple's old keyboards

I *suspect* that the answer is pretty simple and there are some default keyboards e.g. from Dell or something that will meet these requirements with a bit of "neural recalibration".

I think for my purposes the low profile, low force, and low travel distances, will be the most important for preventing inflammation and pain in the small joints of the fingers. Obviously matching other aspects of geometry and kinematics would be a plus for allowing over-trained touch-typing motor programs to transfer, but I'll admit that other physical parameters might allow even fast pain-free typing with some practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your keyword search is 'Apple A1243 US' [searching ANSI doesn't do so well as US]

There are plenty of second hand keyboards on eBay UK, starting around £30 - [sample search](https://www.ebay.co.uk/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=apple+a1243+US&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_sop=15)
(When these were first discontinued the prices shot from the original retail £40 to a colossal £140, but have now settled back again to something more sensible. They're still considered 'desirable' so they do hold their prices])

Alternatively, the modern equivalents are the 'short' A1314 or magic A1644, the direct replacement magic A1843 or TouchID A2449 [touch ID probably needs a recent Mac to function.] Considerably more expensive, retail prices £130 for magic, £200 for TouchID.
BTW, the wireless ones are just as good [& the TouchID on an appropriate Mac is useful] but personally, I wouldn't want to spend another hundred quid just to have no wire either. We have one of these that came with a recent iMac, so it was part of the purchase. I wouldn't bother buying one separately.

Just to note: Don't buy anything 'spares or repairs'. These things are really not consumer fixable. You can't even take them apart easily, they're glued.

*Not coffee-proof, btw ;)*

Comment: Thanks for this! "Apple A1243 US" seems to return results even in the UK, which is wonderful.

Comment: Update on this: At least one Ebay UK seller claiming to sell US keyboards is fraudulent; Keyboard arrived weeks late and they just shipped a UK one instead. I think it might be very hard to successfully source these in the UK. I'd settle for anything ANSI, I hear Netherlands uses the same layout. No clue how to find them though.

Comment: Ah, dammit. Only the US [& some places nearby] use ANSI, everybody else uses ISO, I'm afraid. [Except Japan, who have their own JIS standard]

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for similar options from other brands: Logitech and Cherry have wired keyboard options that work well with Apple and you a search for them on Amazon. If not, you can find decent second-hand options at Amazon too.

Comment: He's not using it with Apple computers, and Logitech and Cherry do not have any wired low-profile ones (like the Apple Magic Keyboard.)